# Capture image from web page using regex

Tags: android, regex, java.util.scanner

I am writing a simple program to capture image resources from the web page. The image items in the html looks like:

```
CASE1:<img src="http://www.aaa.com/bbb.jpg" alt="title bbb" width="350" height="385"/>
```

or

```
CASE2:<img alt="title ccc" src="http://www.ddd.com/bbb.jpg"  width="123" height="456"/>
```

I know how to handle either case separately, take the first one for example:

```
    String CAPTURE = "<img(?:.*)src=\"http://(.*)\\.jpg\"(?:.*)alt=\"(.*?)\"(?:.*)/>";
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    BasicHttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(client
            .execute(new HttpGet(uri), context)
            .getEntity().getContent());
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(CAPTURE);
    while (scanner.findWithinHorizon(pattern, 0) != null) {
        MatchResult r = scanner.match();
        String imageUrl = "http://" +r.group(1)+".jpg";
        String imageTitle = r.group(2);
        //Do something with the image
   }
```

The question is how to write the correct pattern to get all the image items from a web page source code which contains both CASE1 and CASE2? I only want to scan the page once.

Answer (score 1):

Use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/download)

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
...

 Document doc;
 String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0";
try {

    // need http protocol
    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://domain.tld/images.html").userAgent(userAgent).get();

    // get all images
    Elements images = doc.select("img");
    for (Element image: images) {

        // get the values from img attribute (src & alt)
        System.out.println("\nImage: " + image.attr("src"));
        System.out.println("Alt : " + image.attr("alt"));

    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), a HTML parser, its “jquery-like” and “regex” selector
>   syntax is very easy to use and flexible enough to get whatever you
>   want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I cannot accept it. I still need a work around with the regex stuff. But up vote for you.

Comment: Any special reason to use a regex ?

Comment: Nothing special, I want to know if there is any method to handle such case with regex. This might be useful for the content other than html pages. I heard that there is something called "named group" but it is not available on Android.

Comment: It's easier this way ;)

Comment: Sure, for the web page, Jsoup is really a good helper. Thanks a lot for your information.